# Botmaster with socket.io and watson-conversation-ware

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chatbot, watson-conversation

I'm developing a chatbot using masterbot, socket.io, watson-conversation. The problem is that I wasn't able to understand what I need to do to recive the watson welcome message before I begin to send messages. Now I just recive messages after send some text, what I need is recive the first message before send any messager. Is it possible to have it using botmaster?

```js
const SessionWare = require('botmaster-session-ware');
const WatsonConversationWare = require('botmaster-watson-conversation-ware');
const express = require('express'); 
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express(); 

// Rota para index.html
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

const server = app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {  
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

const Botmaster = require('botmaster');
const SocketioBot = require('botmaster-socket.io');

const botmaster = new Botmaster({
  server,
});

const socketioSettings = {
  id: 'SOME_BOT_ID_OF_YOUR_CHOOSING',
  server,
};

const socketioBot = new SocketioBot(socketioSettings);
botmaster.addBot(socketioBot);

const watsonConversationWareOptions = {
  settings: {
    username: ,
    password: ,
    url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/',
    version: 'v1',
    version_date: '2018-02-16'
  },
  workspaceId: 
}

// declaring middleware
const watsonConversationWare = WatsonConversationWare(watsonConversationWareOptions);
botmaster.use(watsonConversationWare);

botmaster.use({
  type: 'incoming',
  name: 'watson-middleware',
  controller: (bot, update) => {
    return bot.sendTextCascadeTo(update.watsonUpdate.output.text, update.sender.id);
  }
});

// This will make our context persist throughout different messages from the
// same user
const sessionWare = new SessionWare();
botmaster.useWrapped(sessionWare.incoming, sessionWare.outgoing);

botmaster.on('error', (bot, err) => { 
  console.log(err.stack); 
});
```

```js
var socket = io('?botmasterUserId=wantedUserId');

var form = document.getElementById('form');
var textInput = document.getElementById('text-input');
var messages = document.getElementById('messages');

form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!textInput.value) {
    return;
  }
  messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    `<li class="user-message">${textInput.value}</li>`);
  
  const update = {
    message: {
      text: textInput.value
    }
  };
  socket.send(update);
  textInput.value = '';
};

socket.on('message', function(botmasterMessage){
  var textMessage = botmasterMessage.message.text;

  messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    `<li class="botmaster-message">${textMessage}</li>`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as you can see you need to send an empty message to receive the **Welcome message**.

*POST Example with a empty message:*

[image]

*Response:*

[image]

**Obs.:** My server expects one JSON like my example, this config will depend of your code in your back-end side, like your example will be the `inputValue.value` inside the `message` object, try to use `inputValue.value || ""`.

- See more about the method send Message with Watson Conversation [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#send_message).